# Select2 set selected value new method

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I use to set the default value on load for a select (using Select2) with a code like this:

```
$('#soff_gar').select2({placeholder: "Scegli", initSelection: true }).select2("val","<?php echo $garante; ?>");
```

Upgrading to version 4.0 on console I read: "Select2: The `select2("val")` method has been deprecated and will be removed in later Select2 versions. Use $element.val() instead." So I tried to change my code to

```
$('#soff_gar').select2({placeholder: "Scegli", initSelection: true }).val("<?php echo $garante; ?>");
```

or

```
$('#soff_gar').select2({placeholder: "Scegli"}).val("<?php echo $garante; ?>");
```

but none of them works. What am I doing wrong? Any hint?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

From [the release notes](http://select2.github.io/announcements-4.0.html#removed-methods):

> You should directly call .val on the underlying  element
>   instead. If you needed the second parameter (triggerChange), you
>   should also call .trigger("change") on the element.
>
> `$("select").val("1"); // instead of $("select").select2("val", "1");`

So, if you have a select element:

```
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

In the past you would have initialised it like so:

`$("#mySelect").select2().select2("val","audi");`

This has been replaced with:

```
$("#mySelect").select2();
$("#mySelect").val("audi").trigger("change");
```

For you, I guess that would translate to:

```
$('#soff_gar').select2({
  placeholder: "Scegli", 
  initSelection: true 
});
$('#soff_gar').val(<?php echo $garante; ?>).trigger("change");
```

Although, is there any reason you're doing this programatically?

With reference to my example, this would also work:

```
<option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>
```

HTH

Comment: So the point is on trigger("change")! Thanks! I read the notes you mention in your answer but didn't get the point. The reason for my code is on how I build the page and increase code readability

Comment: trigger select works but it is really trigger change event so if there is redirect after change, page will be redirect immediately.
It works for me like this:
$("#mySelect").val("audi").select2();

Comment: `<option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>` works for me.